How can I call render ribbon from code?
I have CustomPanel class.
public class CustomPanel : RibbonPanel
{
    public int SelectedItemCount { get; set; }
    private const string SelectedItems = "Seleceted items:";

    public override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output,
                                Ribbon ribbon,
                                Item button,
                                CommandContext context)
    {
        string cachedData = CustomCacheManager.GetCache("selectedItems");

        if (cachedData == null)
        {
            output.Write($"<div><textarea readonly>SelectedItems:0</textarea></div>");
            return;
        }

        var itemIds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(cachedData);

        var htmlOutput = $"<div><textarea readonly>SelectedItems: {itemIds.Count}</textarea></div>";

        output.Write(htmlOutput);
    }
}

I need to call this Render method from my aspx.cs code, How can I do it?
This selecting items on custom aspx modal page:
And this is panel with dynamic html on ribbon in content editor:

I need call rerender ribbon panel or whole ribbon after closing custom modal or on click Add button

You can create custom controls to show inside aspx page by creating codebeside that extends Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl abstract class and registering the namespace for the class using Register directive.

Create the custom control class as below that extends Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl class. This class is used to generate the HTML output.

using Sitecore.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace CustomSitecoreControls.WebControls
{
    public class ShowSelectedItems : WebControl
    {
        protected override void DoRender(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            // Logic to read Selected Items from Cache
            var htmlOutput = $"<div><textarea readonly>SelectedItems:</textarea></div>";
            output.Write(htmlOutput);
        }
    }
}


Thereafter, prefix for the custom contol to be called, is added inside Register directive on the top of the aspx page, wherein namespace and assembly for the class are configured as below.

<%@ Register TagPrefix="csc" Namespace="CustomSitecoreControls.WebControls" Assembly="CustomSitecoreControls" %>


Then finally we call the custom control inside aspx page by adding it as below.

<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <csc:ShowSelectedItems runat="server" />
</form>

Using above way, render method on the custom controls is triggered automatically to display HTML output inside the aspx page.
Update:
You can use any one of the below methods to re-render ribbon panel, on Add button command as below.
protected void Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)
{
  if (args.IsPostBack)
  {
    Context.ClientPage.SendMessage((object) this, "item:refresh");
  }
  else
  {
    // Logic to show aspx page
  }
}

or
protected void Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)
{
  if (args.IsPostBack)
  {
    Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Timer("item:refresh", 500);
  }
  else 
  {
    // Logic to show aspx page
  }
}

Hope this helps!!!

Thank you!
I need to show html on ribbon panel, not aspx page

@SergeyMartynov can you please let me know kind of output you are expecting in ribbon panel... are you looking for showing the same ribbon in your aspx page that comes in content editor.

Wanted to understand little bit on your use case you are trying to achieve..

I want to show html with text on ribbon panel in content editor use chunk -> panel. I maked it, I choised item on my aspx custom modal page, and then I want to see selected items on ribbon panel. But I have problem, because content editor ribbon dont rerender after closing my custom modal page. Ribbon rerender after some action on content editor @ckhanna

I updated question description @ckhanna

@SergeyMartynov I have updated the answer above to refresh ribbon panel..Hope this helps..

I tryed to call ...Timer("item:refresh", 500);, but it dont work when custom modal page opened or after closing.
...Timer("item:refresh", 500); It work when i call it without custom modal page.

@SergeyMartynov Did you tryed Context.ClientPage.SendMessage as well..First option?

Also hope you are adding this code inside Add button command postback as mentioned above....

This postback will run when the modal page is closed..
